# canal and proxy pods stuck in ContainerCreating on windows node in kubernetes cluster

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kube-proxy

We are trying to add a windows node to our centos-based kubernetes cluster with canal pod network manager.

To do so, we built a windows server 1709 VM and followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows to the letter.

As a matter of fact, the powershell scripts successfully joined the cluster

```
NAME    STATUS  ROLES   AGE VERSION EXTERNAL-IP OS-IMAGE        KERNEL-VERSION  CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-node-01 Ready   master  19d v1.9.3  <none>  CentOS Linux 7  (Core)  3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64  docker://1.12.6
k8s-node-02 Ready   <none>  19d v1.9.3  <none>  CentOS Linux 7  (Core)  3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64  docker://1.12.6
k8s-node-03 Ready   <none>  19d v1.9.3  <none>  CentOS Linux 7  (Core)  3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64  docker://1.12.6
k8s-wnode-01    Ready   <none>  17h v1.9.3  <none>  Windows Server  Datacenter  10.0.16299.125
```

and we even deployed a windows-based example app and its service that is running.

```
default       win-webserver-5c4c6df67f-2zllt                  1/1       Running             0          20m       10.244.8.77    k8s-wnode-01
default       win-webserver                  NodePort    10.106.133.105   <none>        80:32415/TCP                                                                                   23h       app=win-webserver
```

but the pod is not reachable by nodeport means. Digging into the issue we found out that both the canal and the kube-proxy pods are stuck

```
kube-system   canal-dm7gl                                     3/3       Running             3          15d       172.16.8.102   k8s-node-01
kube-system   canal-jf5b5                                     3/3       Running             4          15d       172.16.8.104   k8s-node-02
kube-system   canal-kd8nw                                     3/3       Running             3          15d       172.16.8.105   k8s-node-03
kube-system   canal-tmxk5                                     0/3       ContainerCreating   0          18h       192.168.0.1    k8s-wnode-01
kube-system   kube-proxy-fmpvf                                1/1       Running             10         19d       172.16.8.102   k8s-node-01
kube-system   kube-proxy-gpb68                                1/1       Running             7          19d       172.16.8.104   k8s-node-02
kube-system   kube-proxy-l7wjv                                1/1       Running             6          19d       172.16.8.105   k8s-node-03
kube-system   kube-proxy-phqr7                                0/1       ContainerCreating   0          18h       192.168.0.1    k8s-wnode-01
```

and by describing those pods the issues seem to be unrelated:

```
$ kubectl describe pod kube-proxy-phqr7 -n kube-system
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  21m                  kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kube-proxy-token-4cdx4"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  21m                  kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "lib-modules"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  21m                  kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kube-proxy"
  Warning  FailedMount            3m (x17 over 21m)    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "xtables-lock" : open /run/xtables.lock: The system cannot find the path specified.
  Warning  FailedMount            1m (x9 over 19m)     kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  Unable to mount volumes for pod "kube-proxy-phqr7_kube-system(6e18e3c8-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "kube-system"/"kube-proxy-phqr7". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[xtables-lock]

$ kubectl describe pod canal-tmxk5 -n kube-system
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   22m                    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "run"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   22m                    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "canal-token-9twgx"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   22m                    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "lib-modules"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   22m                    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "cni-bin-dir"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   22m                    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "cni-net-dir"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   22m                    kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "flannel-cfg"
  Normal   SandboxChanged          22m (x9 over 22m)      kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m (x311 over 22m)     kubelet, k8s-wnode-01  Failed create pod sandbox.
```

what is xtables-lock and why the windows node is missing this file in the secret volume for the proxy?

why does the pod sandbox (and what is it?) fail to create for canal and where should i look to find more info?

The documentation for windows kubernetes node is really lacking and I don't know where to look as all the google results are about linux nodes and I cannot seem to find a way to apply the proposed fixes on windows as it's a completely different environment.

the following are log dumps from the kubelet console on the windows node

```
E0307 11:03:32.011134   80996 kubelet.go:1624] Unable to mount volumes for pod "kube-proxy-phqr7_kube-system(6e18e3c8-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "kube-system"/"kube-proxy-phqr7". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[xtables-lock]; skipping pod
E0307 11:03:32.011134   80996 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 6e18e3c8-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24 ("kube-proxy-phqr7_kube-system(6e18e3c8-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"), skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "kube-system"/"kube-proxy-phqr7". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[xtables-lock]
I0307 11:03:32.011134   80996 server.go:231] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-proxy-phqr7", UID:"6e18e3c8-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"2241119", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedMount' Unable to mount volumes for pod "kube-proxy-phqr7_kube-system(6e18e3c8-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "kube-system"/"kube-proxy-phqr7". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[xtables-lock]
...
I0307 11:03:32.633168   80996 kuberuntime_manager.go:853] getSandboxIDByPodUID got sandbox IDs ["590cac5a4ba9ec641835823eab19250a8d7984d3ba95da3c79af486f021d2161" "fb9dd26c3f6f26034aec38d2a82efe063ab30e0316323d7514556d8e74455b5d" "5b7de8875db3942b2b0d7538c0b5204c55fa405f9835995e68a15886f0c9e149"] for pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"
I0307 11:03:32.640170   80996 generic.go:380] PLEG: Write status for canal-tmxk5/kube-system: &container.PodStatus{ID:"6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24", Name:"canal-tmxk5", Namespace:"kube-system", IP:"", ContainerStatuses:[]*container.ContainerStatus{}, SandboxStatuses:[]*runtime.PodSandboxStatus{(*runtime.PodSandboxStatus)(0xc042a334f0), (*runtime.PodSandboxStatus)(0xc042a337c0), (*runtime.PodSandboxStatus)(0xc042a33ae0)}} (err: <nil>)
I0307 11:03:32.644184   80996 kubelet.go:1880] SyncLoop (PLEG): "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24", Type:"ContainerDied", Data:"590cac5a4ba9ec641835823eab19250a8d7984d3ba95da3c79af486f021d2161"}
I0307 11:03:32.644184   80996 kubelet_pods.go:1349] Generating status for "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"
I0307 11:03:32.645170   80996 kubelet_pods.go:1314] pod waiting > 0, pending
W0307 11:03:32.645170   80996 pod_container_deletor.go:77] Container "590cac5a4ba9ec641835823eab19250a8d7984d3ba95da3c79af486f021d2161" not found in pod's containers
I0307 11:03:32.645170   80996 kubelet_pods.go:1349] Generating status for "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"
I0307 11:03:32.645170   80996 kubelet_pods.go:1314] pod waiting > 0, pending
I0307 11:03:32.645170   80996 status_manager.go:353] Ignoring same status for pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)", status: {Phase:Pending Conditions:[{Type:Initialized Status:True LastProbeTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC LastTransitionTime:2018-03-06 16:39:31 +0100 CET Reason: Message:} {Type:Ready Status:False LastProbeTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC LastTransitionTime:2018-03-06 16:39:31 +0100 CET Reason:ContainersNotReady Message:containers with unready status: [calico-node install-cni kube-flannel]} {Type:PodScheduled Status:True LastProbeTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC LastTransitionTime:2018-03-06 16:41:18 +0100 CET Reason: Message:}] Message: Reason: HostIP:192.168.0.1 PodIP:192.168.0.1 StartTime:2018-03-06 16:39:31 +0100 CET InitContainerStatuses:[] ContainerStatuses:[{Name:calico-node State:{Waiting:&ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:ContainerCreating,Message:,} Running:nil Terminated:nil} LastTerminationState:{Waiting:nil Running:nil Terminated:nil} Ready:false RestartCount:0 Image:quay.io/calico/node:v2.6.7 ImageID: ContainerID:} {Name:install-cni State:{Waiting:&ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:ContainerCreating,Message:,} Running:nil Terminated:nil} LastTerminationState:{Waiting:nil Running:nil Terminated:nil} Ready:false RestartCount:0 Image:quay.io/calico/cni:v1.11.2 ImageID: ContainerID:} {Name:kube-flannel State:{Waiting:&ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:ContainerCreating,Message:,} Running:nil Terminated:nil} LastTerminationState:{Waiting:nil Running:nil Terminated:nil} Ready:false RestartCount:0 Image:quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.9.1 ImageID: ContainerID:}] QOSClass:Burstable}
I0307 11:03:32.651168   80996 volume_manager.go:342] Waiting for volumes to attach and mount for pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"
I0307 11:03:32.657170   80996 kubelet.go:1263] Container garbage collection succeeded
I0307 11:03:32.697183   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/configmap
I0307 11:03:32.710179   80996 reconciler.go:264] operationExecutor.MountVolume started for volume "flannel-cfg" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configmap/6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24-flannel-cfg") pod "canal-tmxk5" (UID: "6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24") Volume is already mounted to pod, but remount was requested.
I0307 11:03:32.710179   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/secret
I0307 11:03:32.710179   80996 reconciler.go:264] operationExecutor.MountVolume started for volume "canal-token-9twgx" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24-canal-token-9twgx") pod "canal-tmxk5" (UID: "6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24") Volume is already mounted to pod, but remount was requested.
I0307 11:03:32.711174   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/host-path
I0307 11:03:32.711174   80996 secret.go:186] Setting up volume canal-token-9twgx for pod 6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24 at c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx
I0307 11:03:32.711174   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/empty-dir
I0307 11:03:32.711174   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/empty-dir
I0307 11:03:32.712174   80996 empty_dir.go:264] pod 6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24: mounting tmpfs for volume wrapped_canal-token-9twgx
I0307 11:03:32.710179   80996 configmap.go:187] Setting up volume flannel-cfg for pod 6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24 at c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg
I0307 11:03:32.713173   80996 mount_windows.go:55] azureMount: mounting source ("tmpfs"), target ("c:\\var\\lib\\kubelet\\pods\\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\\volumes\\kubernetes.io~secret\\canal-token-9twgx"), with options ([])
I0307 11:03:32.713173   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/empty-dir
I0307 11:03:32.715190   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/empty-dir
I0307 11:03:32.716175   80996 round_trippers.go:436] GET https://172.16.8.102:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets/canal-token-9twgx?resourceVersion=0 200 OK in 1 milliseconds
I0307 11:03:32.717180   80996 secret.go:213] Received secret kube-system/canal-token-9twgx containing (3) pieces of data, 1884 total bytes
I0307 11:03:32.718174   80996 round_trippers.go:436] GET https://172.16.8.102:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/canal-config?resourceVersion=0 200 OK in 1 milliseconds
I0307 11:03:32.718174   80996 atomic_writer.go:332] c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx: current paths:   [c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.050789875\ca.crt c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.050789875\namespace c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.050789875\token]
I0307 11:03:32.718174   80996 atomic_writer.go:344] c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx: new paths:       [ca.crt namespace token]
I0307 11:03:32.719173   80996 atomic_writer.go:347] c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx: paths to remove: map[c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.050789875\token:{} c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.050789875\ca.crt:{} c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.050789875\namespace:{}]
I0307 11:03:32.726175   80996 atomic_writer.go:159] pod kube-system/canal-tmxk5 volume canal-token-9twgx: write required for target directory c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx
I0307 11:03:32.734177   80996 atomic_writer.go:176] pod kube-system/canal-tmxk5 volume canal-token-9twgx: performed write of new data to ts data directory: c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~secret\canal-token-9twgx\..2018_03_07_10_03_32.145900189
I0307 11:03:32.727175   80996 configmap.go:214] Received configMap kube-system/canal-config containing (4) pieces of data, 911 total bytes
I0307 11:03:32.798178   80996 atomic_writer.go:332] c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg: current paths:   [c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\canal_iface c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\cni_network_config c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\masquerade c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\net-conf.json]
I0307 11:03:32.798178   80996 atomic_writer.go:344] c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg: new paths:       [canal_iface cni_network_config masquerade net-conf.json]
I0307 11:03:32.798178   80996 atomic_writer.go:347] c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg: paths to remove: map[c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\masquerade:{} c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\net-conf.json:{} c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\canal_iface:{} c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_27.611158500\cni_network_config:{}]
I0307 11:03:32.799180   80996 atomic_writer.go:159] pod kube-system/canal-tmxk5 volume flannel-cfg: write required for target directory c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg
I0307 11:03:32.811187   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/configmap
I0307 11:03:32.812179   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/host-path
I0307 11:03:32.835183   80996 atomic_writer.go:176] pod kube-system/canal-tmxk5 volume flannel-cfg: performed write of new data to ts data directory: c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\flannel-cfg\..2018_03_07_10_03_32.269248344
I0307 11:03:32.912190   80996 volume_host.go:218] using default mounter/exec for kubernetes.io/host-path
I0307 11:03:32.956200   80996 volume_manager.go:371] All volumes are attached and mounted for pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"
I0307 11:03:32.956200   80996 kuberuntime_manager.go:442] Syncing Pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)": &Pod{ObjectMeta:k8s_io_apimachinery_pkg_apis_meta_v1.ObjectMeta{Name:canal-tmxk5,GenerateName:canal-,Namespace:kube-system,SelfLink:/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/canal-tmxk5,UID:6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24,ResourceVersion:2241118,Generation:0,CreationTimestamp:2018-03-06 16:38:34 +0100 CET,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{controller-revision-hash: 1120593895,k8s-app: canal,pod-template-generation: 1,},Annotations:map[string]string{kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2018-03-07T10:28:11.9157574+01:00,kubernetes.io/config.source: api,scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ,},OwnerReferences:[{extensions/v1beta1 DaemonSet canal b747d502-1614-11e8-931d-000c299d5d24 0xc042d93dd8 0xc042d93dd9}],Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,Initializers:nil,},Spec:PodSpec{Volumes:[{lib-modules {HostPathVolumeSource{Path:/lib/modules,Type:*,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}} {var-run-calico {&HostPathVolumeSource{Path:/var/run/calico,Type:*,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}} {cni-bin-dir {&HostPathVolumeSource{Path:/opt/cni/bin,Type:*,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}} {cni-net-dir {&HostPathVolumeSource{Path:/etc/cni/net.d,Type:*,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}} {run {&HostPathVolumeSource{Path:/run,Type:*,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}} {flannel-cfg {nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil &ConfigMapVolumeSource{LocalObjectReference:LocalObjectReference{Name:canal-config,},Items:[],DefaultMode:*420,Optional:nil,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}} {canal-token-9twgx {nil nil nil nil nil &SecretVolumeSource{SecretName:canal-token-9twgx,Items:[],DefaultMode:*420,Optional:nil,} nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil}}],Containers:[{calico-node quay.io/calico/node:v2.6.7 [] []  [] [] [{DATASTORE_TYPE kubernetes nil} {FELIX_LOGSEVERITYSYS info nil} {CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND none nil} {CLUSTER_TYPE k8s,canal nil} {CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING true nil} {FELIX_IPTABLESREFRESHINTERVAL 60 nil} {FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT false nil} {WAIT_FOR_DATASTORE true nil} {IP  nil} {NODENAME  EnvVarSource{FieldRef:&ObjectFieldSelector{APIVersion:v1,FieldPath:spec.nodeName,},ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:nil,SecretKeyRef:nil,}} {FELIX_DEFAULTENDPOINTTOHOSTACTION ACCEPT nil} {FELIX_HEALTHENABLED true nil}] {map[] map[cpu:{{250 -3} {<nil>} 250m DecimalSI}]} [{lib-modules true /lib/modules  <nil>} {var-run-calico false /var/run/calico  <nil>} {canal-token-9twgx true /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount  <nil>}] [] &Probe{Handler:Handler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:&HTTPGetAction{Path:/liveness,Port:9099,Host:,Scheme:HTTP,HTTPHeaders:[],},TCPSocket:nil,},InitialDelaySeconds:10,TimeoutSeconds:1,PeriodSeconds:10,SuccessThreshold:1,FailureThreshold:6,} &Probe{Handler:Handler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:&HTTPGetAction{Path:/readiness,Port:9099,Host:,Scheme:HTTP,HTTPHeaders:[],},TCPSocket:nil,},InitialDelaySeconds:0,TimeoutSeconds:1,PeriodSeconds:10,SuccessThreshold:1,FailureThreshold:3,} nil /dev/termination-log File IfNotPresent &SecurityContext{Capabilities:nil,Privileged:*true,SELinuxOptions:nil,RunAsUser:nil,RunAsNonRoot:nil,ReadOnlyRootFilesystem:nil,AllowPrivilegeEscalation:nil,} false false false} {install-cni quay.io/calico/cni:v1.11.2 [/install-cni.sh] []  [] [] [{CNI_CONF_NAME 10-calico.conflist nil} {CNI_NETWORK_CONFIG  &EnvVarSource{FieldRef:nil,ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:&ConfigMapKeySelector{LocalObjectReference:LocalObjectReference{Name:canal-config,},Key:cni_network_config,Optional:nil,},SecretKeyRef:nil,}} {KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME  &EnvVarSource{FieldRef:&ObjectFieldSelector{APIVersion:v1,FieldPath:spec.nodeName,},ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:nil,SecretKeyRef:nil,}}] {map[] map[]} [{cni-bin-dir false /host/opt/cni/bin  <nil>} {cni-net-dir false /host/etc/cni/net.d  <nil>} {canal-token-9twgx true /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount  <nil>}] [] nil nil nil /dev/termination-log File IfNotPresent nil false false false} {kube-flannel quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.9.1 [/opt/bin/flanneld --ip-masq --kube-subnet-mgr] []  [] [] [{POD_NAME  &EnvVarSource{FieldRef:&ObjectFieldSelector{APIVersion:v1,FieldPath:metadata.name,},ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:nil,SecretKeyRef:nil,}} {POD_NAMESPACE  &EnvVarSource{FieldRef:&ObjectFieldSelector{APIVersion:v1,FieldPath:metadata.namespace,},ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:nil,SecretKeyRef:nil,}} {FLANNELD_IFACE  &EnvVarSource{FieldRef:nil,ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:&ConfigMapKeySelector{LocalObjectReference:LocalObjectReference{Name:canal-config,},Key:canal_iface,Optional:nil,},SecretKeyRef:nil,}} {FLANNELD_IP_MASQ  &EnvVarSource{FieldRef:nil,ResourceFieldRef:nil,ConfigMapKeyRef:&ConfigMapKeySelector{LocalObjectReference:LocalObjectReference{Name:canal-config,},Key:masquerade,Optional:nil,},SecretKeyRef:nil,}}] {map[] map[]} [{run false /run  <nil>} {flannel-cfg false /etc/kube-flannel/  <nil>} {canal-token-9twgx true /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount  <nil>}] [] nil nil nil /dev/termination-log File IfNotPresent &SecurityContext{Capabilities:nil,Privileged:*true,SELinuxOptions:nil,RunAsUser:nil,RunAsNonRoot:nil,ReadOnlyRootFilesystem:nil,AllowPrivilegeEscalation:nil,} false false false}],RestartPolicy:Always,TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:*0,ActiveDeadlineSeconds:nil,DNSPolicy:ClusterFirst,NodeSelector:map[string]string{},ServiceAccountName:canal,DeprecatedServiceAccount:canal,NodeName:k8s-wnode-01,HostNetwork:true,HostPID:false,HostIPC:false,SecurityContext:&PodSecurityContext{SELinuxOptions:nil,RunAsUser:nil,RunAsNonRoot:nil,SupplementalGroups:[],FSGroup:nil,},ImagePullSecrets:[],Hostname:,Subdomain:,Affinity:nil,SchedulerName:default-scheduler,InitContainers:[],AutomountServiceAccountToken:nil,Tolerations:[{ Exists  NoSchedule <nil>} {CriticalAddonsOnly Exists   <nil>} { Exists  NoExecute <nil>} {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready Exists  NoExecute <nil>} {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable Exists  NoExecute <nil>} {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure Exists  NoSchedule <nil>} {node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure Exists  NoSchedule <nil>}],HostAliases:[],PriorityClassName:,Priority:nil,DNSConfig:nil,},Status:PodStatus{Phase:Pending,Conditions:[{Initialized True 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2018-03-06 16:39:31 +0100 CET  } {Ready False 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2018-03-06 16:39:31 +0100 CET ContainersNotReady containers with unready status: [calico-node install-cni kube-flannel]} {PodScheduled True 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2018-03-06 16:41:18 +0100 CET  }],Message:,Reason:,HostIP:192.168.0.1,PodIP:192.168.0.1,StartTime:2018-03-06 16:39:31 +0100 CET,ContainerStatuses:[{calico-node {ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:ContainerCreating,Message:,} nil nil} {nil nil nil} false 0 quay.io/calico/node:v2.6.7  } {install-cni {&ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:ContainerCreating,Message:,} nil nil} {nil nil nil} false 0 quay.io/calico/cni:v1.11.2  } {kube-flannel {&ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:ContainerCreating,Message:,} nil nil} {nil nil nil} false 0 quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.9.1  }],QOSClass:Burstable,InitContainerStatuses:[],},}
I0307 11:03:32.958189   80996 kuberuntime_manager.go:403] No ready sandbox for pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)" can be found. Need to start a new one
I0307 11:03:32.958189   80996 kuberuntime_manager.go:571] computePodActions got {KillPod:true CreateSandbox:true SandboxID:590cac5a4ba9ec641835823eab19250a8d7984d3ba95da3c79af486f021d2161 Attempt:518 NextInitContainerToStart:nil ContainersToStart:[0 1 2] ContainersToKill:map[]} for pod "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)"
I0307 11:03:32.959195   80996 kuberuntime_manager.go:589] Stopping PodSandbox for "canal-tmxk5_kube-system(6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24)", will start new one
I0307 11:03:32.959195   80996 server.go:231] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"canal-tmxk5", UID:"6e16e04d-2154-11e8-827c-000c299d5d24", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"2241118", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'SandboxChanged' Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

Comment: Having the same problem. If yo found a solution would be great if you could share it.

Comment: I didn't abandon you, it's just that i don't have a solution. I switched my entire cluster (the linux hosts) to plain calico instead of canal and have yet to try again to integrate a windows node in it.